# Passing model information to RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I have this line of code:

`<% Html.RenderPartial("VenuesList"); %>`

What I need to do is pass it my model via the additional parameters available in the overides. What do I write? My model is Venue. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962.aspx) allowing you to pass a model to the partial:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("VenuesList", Model.SomeProperty); %>
```

or directly the model if it is of the correct type as expected by the partial:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("VenuesList", Model); %>
```

Comment: Tried doing that but I still get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @Cameron, saying that you are getting a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` without providing exactly where this exception occurs and provide a full stacktrace is like saying nothing. Do you really expect me helping you in any different way than saying: *you have a null object somewhere that you are trying to access, so instantiate it before using it*.